# Laravel 4 - views look like siblings but extended as not siblings

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel, and it uses for me weird view extending method.

Lets say I have 3 view files:

```
  template.blade.php
     form.blade.php
     filteredData.blade.php
```

Now I organized those files as

template is highest one
form.blade is extending template.blade

and filteredData is extending form.

Which works, but does not make sense for me, because filtered data by the logic is not a child, it is more like sibling to the form. It is only loaded when there is data.

Could you give me advice how to think?

I also cannot place it straight in the template, because template is for all website pages, and not everywhere is needed a form with filtered data.

Do I have to create 4th file, lets say FormAndFilter.blade.php which has 2 blocks - form and filteredData? So then it will extend the template.

Then form will will extend FormAndFilter.blade.php

and also filteredData will extend FormAndFilter.blade.php

so it will look more like siblings.

But then how will I call it in the controller function?

Now (havign those 3 files) I call

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('filteredData', $this->viewData);
```

If I have siblings - one of them does not get called. I call form or filtered data. I dont get.

Btw

```
$this->layout->content
```

fills in as I understand @yield('content'); which is in the template.

**Edited**

Finally after long strugling found the way which looks like siblings, but used 4th view:

```
$form = View::make('form');
    $filteredData = View::make('filteredData');

    $turnover = View::make('turnover')
        ->with('form', $form)
        ->with('filtered', $filteredData);


    return View::make('layout', array('content' => $turnover));
```

And the 4th view - turnover.blade.php looks like this:

```
turnover

{{ $form }}

{{ $filtered }}
```

And thanks to this guy who wrote in page:

https://coderwall.com/p/2v7urq

I wish this was in laravel documentation.

Comment: I know you've found a solution (and it would be better to have posted as an answer than adding to the question) but is filteredData form validation information? I may have a more elegant solution for you.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure to post as an answer or not but now will know :) No, filteredData is data returned from database, depending on what in the form was select.